# Improving the run time of a DW query

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016, optimization, performance-tuning

I have a user running query which is sometimes under 10 seconds while other time going over 30 minutes.

This is not a store proc , he is doing it manually from his machine to get data and later after extraction just push it to other application for data visualization

Below is the Query i tried to create which is similar to my user query, logic wise. But since i am still figuring out how to run ETL package on WideWorldImporter database to get it up to date, cant really repro the run time.

> For my env: Fact table is around 6 TB. What i have noticed is around
> 10K rows fetched is varying between 10-30secs while anything over 60K
> rows goes over 10 mins

Query below

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
Select * from  [Fact].[Transaction] f
INNER JOIN  [Dimension].[Customer] dc  on dc.[Customer Key] =f.[Customer Key]
INNER JOIN  [Dimension].[Date] dd on dd.[Date] =f.[Date Key]
INNER JOIN  [Dimension].[Supplier] ds  on ds.[Supplier Key] =f.[Supplier Key]
INNER JOIN  [Dimension].[Transaction Type] dt  on dt.[Transaction Type Key] =f.[Transaction Type Key]
INNER JOIN [Dimension].[Payment Method] pm on pm.[Payment Method Key] =f.[Payment Method Key]
WHERE f.[Date Key]>= convert(varchar,getdate(),112) and 
f.[Lineage Key] between DATEDIFF(SECOND,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) -300 AND DATEDIFF(SECOND,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
ORDER BY [Transaction Key]
```

Actual query has inner join to almost 10 more tables.

[image]

`Lineage_key` is INT NOT NULL and we have NC index on this column as the only leading key

Index:-
[image]

Is there something i can do with Query tuning as index look good?

Plan:- I can paste the part of plan as captured, rest it cant fit due to 30 odd inner joins.

[image]

Edit-

I tried to look at the plan which is too complicated chain as there are 30 odd inner joins. So would try my best to paste. But i found something interesting. I am seeing that compile time is around 8 secs in total of 14 sec run. So i think problem seems more on very high compile time. Is there a way we can avoid compilation time when query has joins with so many tables?

Ran wait stats for 10 min interval when same query ran 8 mins and other time  22 secs. Both queries i ran from SSMS.

[image]

Comment: [Getting Help With A Slow Query](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/)

Comment: Also while or after running the query check it's session's wait stats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @ErikDarling: I do have an exec plan from prod but due to PI compliance cant show here. I am trying to replicate my problem on wideworldimporter database since schema wise they look bit same. However data loading in this sample database  i am still wandering to get it up to date as default one seems loaded with 2013 only.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Sure let me update question once i have handy

Comment: @Newbie-DBA You can anonymize the **execution plan** with [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/sql-performance/anonymize-your-plans) and then post it here since it is not the same as the original plan and won't have any identifiable information.

Comment: @J.D.- Sure, i will try my best because the plan is actually like a chain because of 30 odd inner joins. I had some finding and update my question

Comment: @J.D. Tried my best to add info and plan

Comment: Better to post the plan using PasteThePlan.com .

Comment: @Newbie-DBA Yea sorry, I should've said the following: After you anonymize it, you can view the XML for the anonymous plan, copy and paste that XML in [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan) and upload it and then link it here. There's a lot of performance debugging information not visible when you take a screenshot.

Comment: I can see some things that do pop out so far like the fact there's so many joins going on, most with index scans, some with operator warnings. But having the performance details once you upload the **execution plan** to Paste The Plan will be a lot more telling of your root issues.

Comment: @J.D. Unfortunately copy/paste over the VPN does not work for me, that was the reason i pasted the plan

Comment: @Newbie-DBA Unfortunately we won't be able to tell much from a screenshot. I'm very surprised you can't copy and paste within the same machine though (I know across RDP sometimes bugs out). You can actually save the anonymized **execution plan** as a file, email the file to yourself (or whatever file transfer means you want), and on another computer open it and copy and paste the XML of the **execution plan** to Paste The Plan.

Comment: Is the query plan using the default CE or the Legacy CE? Plan XML will specify CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70" for Legacy CE and higher version for default CE (eg 130 for SQL Sever 2016 default CE). If Legacy CE, are any of the ascending key trace flags in use (2389 + 2390 or 4139 which is the newer trace flag superceding 2389 + 2390). Fact.Transaction.[Date Key] which has an NCI especially has me wondering about ascending key effect.

Comment: @sqL_handLe: CEModelversion=130 from what i checked